# Take a file and copy and rename multiple times over certain folders

Tags: powershell

I have a file (blank.xls) that I want to copy multiple times and rename into the following format:

1 - April\01042018.xls
1 - April\02042018.xls
...
12 - March\31032019.xls

The folders ideally should be created also.

I don’t mind if every month has a file up to 31 as that’s easy enough to delete.

I’ve tried to play about with Powershell but it’s not my strong point - I’m just looking for a pointer in the right direction if possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Searching for PowerShell date, copy file ++ either here or on google will return lots of results to get you started. `Copy-Item` copies files. You should look into the `Datetime`-class to work with dates (creating the names ++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. The files and folders are created in the same folder as the template-file.

```
$startdate = [datetime]"04/01/2018"
$untildate = [datetime]"04/01/2019" #Untildate NOT included
$template = Get-Item "D:\Test\blank.xlsx"

$duration = $untildate - $startdate

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $duration.Days; $i++) {

    #Compute new name/path
    $d = $startdate.AddDays($i)
    $month = ($d.Month - $startdate.Month) + 12 * ($d.Year - $startdate.Year) + 1
    $newpart = "{0} - {1}" -f $month, $d.ToString("MMM\\ddMMyyyy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    $NewFilePath = $template.FullName.Replace($template.BaseName,$newpart)

    #Create new copy of template
    try {
        $template | Copy-Item -Destination $NewFilePath
    } catch [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException] {
        #Folder is missing, create destination and retry
        New-Item -Path (Split-Path -Path $NewFilePath) -ItemType Container > $null
        $template | Copy-Item -Destination $NewFilePath
    }

}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Sorry for not replying earlier. I was trying to create directories first then files in each directory. Fell a bit stupid now for not realising to just make it as part of the file path. Thanks again!